# must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function --upgrading to rails 4

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am upgrading from rails 3.2 to rails 4 and I this new error I have not been able to get rid off:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "answers.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function LINE 1: ...IN (3778, 3779, 3780, 3783, 3786, 3788) ORDER BY "answers".... ^ : SELECT sum(CAST(answer AS FLOAT) / (length(questions.possible_answers) - length(replace(questions.possible_answers,';','')) + 1)) as rating FROM "answers" INNER JOIN "questions" ON "questions"."id" = "answers"."question_id" WHERE "answers"."survey_id" = $1 AND ("answers"."created_at" BETWEEN '2016-03-28 00:00:00.000000' AND '2016-04-03 23:59:59.999999') AND "answers"."question_id" IN (3778, 3779, 3780, 3783, 3786, 3788) ORDER BY "answers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

My query is the following:

```
answer_query = Answer.joins(:question).where(:created_at => start..finish, :question_id => questions_evaluation, :survey_id => survey_id)
sum = answer_query.select("sum(CAST(answer AS FLOAT) / (length(questions.possible_answers) - length(replace(questions.possible_answers,';','')) + 1)) as rating").first['rating'].to_f
```

So the error is happening in the second line.

I have tried adding `unscoped` as suggested [here](https://makandracards.com/bitcrowd/32883-pg-groupingerror-error-column-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause-or-be-used-in-an-aggregate-function-in-rails-while-trying-group) but then I get a different error related to the questions table.

Other posts have suggested removing wild cards, so I added .select("answers, questions.possible_answers"), but then I get

> column "answers.*" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I am not sure what else to try

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with calling `first`  I had to change my code to:

```
answer_query.select("sum(CAST(answer AS FLOAT) / (length(questions.possible_answers) - length(replace(questions.possible_answers,';','')) + 1)) as rating").limit(1).to_a.first.attributes['rating'].to_f
```